# In KNN, why is the data the model?

Tags: machine-learning, knn, nearest-neighbor

In the machine learning lecture slide, it is said that there is no specific model for KNN where the data is the model of KNN.

The previous assignment was NCC(Nearest Centroid Classifier) where there were two methods, one was fit_ncc, and the other was predict_ncc. So fit_ncc creates a model and using this model, predict_ncc makes a prediction.

However, for KNN, it is written that the data is the model. This statement is not clear to me and my question is why data is the model for KNN?

Please see the attached screenshot:

[image: lecture slide screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think that means, that in knn model fit method just remembers data, and predict method calculates distance matrix for each test data sample using some kind of distance metrics(Manhattan or Euclidean distances),and predicts the label of the most frequent one among k nearest samples from train dataset.
Here's links about distance metrics:

[Importance of Distance Metrics in Machine Learning Modelling](https://towardsdatascience.com/importance-of-distance-metrics-in-machine-learning-modelling-e51395ffe60d)

[Types of metrics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Distance.html)